# How to count the number of matching items in pandas dataframe column from another column?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, count

**In this small dataframe:**

```
d1 = pd.read_csv('to_count.mcve.txt', sep='\t')

pos   M1          M2      F1
23    A,B,A,C,D   A,C,B   A
24    A,B,B,C,B   A,B,A   B
28    C,B,C,D,E   B,C     E
```

I want to count how many of the values in F1 are in M1 and M2. As, a learning process I have broken it down into pieces.

Expected final output:

```
pos   M1  M2  F1
23    2   1   1
24    3   1   1
28    1   0   1
```

**What I tried:**

```
d1 = d1.set_index(['pos'], append=True) # to set the pos value aside for simplicity
```

I can either use any of the methods (which are not totally working though) but want to learn the process.

**Then:** Do a direct count in one line

```
d1_count = d1.apply(lambda x: d1.count(d1['F1']))
```

This is throwing an error message. I know I am doing it wrong.
So, what is wrong with my approach? and how could I have done a better job?

Any suggestion with explanation (for any or all methods) is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `apply` method to loop through data frame rows and `str.count` method to count the number of appearances:

```
df[['M1', 'M2']] = df.apply(lambda x: x.loc['M1':'M2'].str.count(x.F1), 1)
df

#  pos  M1  M2  F1
#0  23  2   1   A
#1  24  3   1   B
#2  28  1   0   E
```

---

If you want to count all columns except for `pos`:

```
df.set_index('pos').apply(lambda x: x.str.count(x.F1), 1).reset_index()

#  pos  M1  M2  F1
#0  23  2   1   1
#1  24  3   1   1
#2  28  1   0   1
```

Comment: What you suggested is good. But, there is a problem when I have lots of columns. I want to skip mentioning the column at all.

Comment: I just changed the output a little bit. If I can just read the values for `F1` without mentioning the `columns`, I can later drop the `F1` and then add from previous dataframe. Any way to make it work?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Maybe use column positions?

Comment: I mean I don't want to indicate `['M1', 'M2']` since in my original data I will have a lots of columns.

Comment: Why is `F1` column all 1s?

Comment: I just changed the output. Because the number of items of `F1` in `F1` will always be `1`. Btw, the output in `F1` column doesn't matter, i just want to take the approach which is more simples and comprehensible.

Comment: Do you want to count F1 in all other columns except for `pos` column?

Comment: yes. for that reason I actually moved `pos` to index, so it wouldn't do any count.